# formatting an unallocated portion of a disk drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive

When I cloned my c drive to my new seagate 4 TB drive, it only incluced 2048 MB. Now the rest of the drive is labelled "unallocated" and I can't do anything with it. If I format the disk, I can only format the Healthy primary partition.

Comment: can you edit your post with a screenshot of the disk management view of the disk and the output of `list disk` in the `diskpart` run from cmd? (first run diskpart and then in the utility the list disk command)

Comment: Does your computer support UEFI BIOS or is it on Legacy BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your old harddisk was formated with an MBR partition table - this supports no more than 2 TB. To use all space, you have to convert to a GPT partition table or dynamic disks.

Be aware: Older Mainboards may  have problems booting a GPT-partitioned drive.